# Sitefinity personalization by Time of Day

Tags: sitefinity

I have created several "user segments" and added corresponding personalized versions of content blocks in a page.  For some simple segments, for instance, that just check if the user has visited a specific page, it works flawlessly.

But for others, specifically when adding the "Time of day" characteristic, it fails to select any of the user segments and displays the default content.

I've created a segment that just checks if the time of day is "between 3AM and 11:30 AM" and I set its priority to "1."  My understanding is that, because it is the top priority item, that even though there are other segments that could apply, this is the one that will be chosen if the current time of day is in that time frame.  But its not working.

Any thoughts on how I may be misunderstanding the process? or tips/struggles others have overcome working w/ Sitefinity personalization?  Thanks!

EDIT: if I set the Time of Day segment criteria to "IS NOT" between 12:00 AM and 11:59 PM then it works. In other words, matching the time of day is always returning false unless I specifically check if its false, in which case it is and the personalized content displays.  What the heck?

Comment: How are you testing, through the preview tool in Sitefinity? Or on the front end in your browser? If the latter, have you made sure cookies were wiped out on the domain from previous sessions before re-testing? I've run into issues in both scenarios before

Comment: Also, have you checked using it at other times of the day? Could it be related to different time zones?

Comment: Thanks @StuFurlong for your thoughts. In the preview tool, everything looks great; it's the browser that's not seeing the right time-based personalized content. It does not appear to be cookie related as it happens across new browsers, incognito/private modes and on both localhost, our dev site and a second dev site on a 3rd server, even on the first visit.  Per your second question, I've tested multiple time blocks and also with just one time segment that was 12:01 AM to 11:59 PM and it still doesn't work, its just ingores the time of day criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this problem only exists for me when connecting to the webserver while running the VPN that we've been using throughout development.  I have not narrowed down what about that process could possibly be causing the problem, but at this point it seems that it's not so much a sitefinity issue or configuration problem on our server end.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the case with 10.2 and everything is working fine. I found this closed bug in the [feedback portal](https://feedback.telerik.com/Project/153/Feedback/Details/186509-personalization-by-time-of-day-doesnt-work-when-time-is-from-pm-to-am). Review your version. In case that you cannot upgrade you can try to implement your [own criteria](https://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/peter-filipov/posts/peter-filipov-blog/2017/04/03/personalize-content-with-sitefinity).

Comment: Thank you for looking into this and testing.  It appears the problem I was having is related to the VPN I was using, perhaps it strips out the time in the headers, or something else, I don't really know but I don't believe it's a problem to Sitefinity after all.  The site I've been working on launched the other day and the time-based personalization is working in production!